# Dismission of ephemeral message

Tags: discord, discord.js

Do we have a way to differentiate between a dismissed ephemeral message and a non-dismissed one In discord?
do we have a special property in the message object ? some API to fetch this info ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to get ephemeral messages.

Comment: I want to create a UX around ephemeral messages, they are really user friendly, because they let the user stay in the same channel without having to DM and he is the only one who can see the message. However ,unfortunately, we can't delete ephemeral messages or get a dismiss event making everything harder :(

Comment: i mean depending on what u are doing. you can create temp channels only said user can see.

Comment: the bot will pin a message in a specific channel so i want the whole experience to be there for all users

Comment: hmm. what exactly is the goal here?

Comment: Our discord members need to redeem their vouchers. The pinned message contains some buttons to interact with bot. there are multiple steps to finish the process. the bot will use ephemeral messages to respond to user interaction.

Comment: you could use modals.

Comment: yes exactly I'm using modals. the bot will respond with ephemeral messages to the modal submit interaction but I want to keep only one ephemeral message that is visible for the user and I keep editing this one (I achieved this by storing a reference of the interaction). However the only  complication is when the user dismiss the message. So I don't have any idea on what is currently visible for the user on the channel.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by removing all the content of last message so the user won't give a big attention and simply will dismiss it by clicking or ignore it.

[image]